# Search for a specific value in a csv file with bash

Tags: bash, grep

I have a simple "students" csv file with 5 columns and few lines, the first column is for names. I just want to prompt the user for a name and see if we have it on the csv file but it does not work and I do not know why. Also, I do not want to exit the program if it is not found, I just want to print the message

```
read -p "What is your name?: " arg1
if grep -q arg1 "$names.csv"; then
   $ printf "%s\n" "We got you!"
else
   $ printf "%s\n" "Sorry, you are not on the list!"
```

csv file with input:

```
Name,R1, R2 , R3 , R4
James,"35,587","55,800,000,000","1,567,988","491,000,000,000"
Tom,"16,000","11,300,000,000","706,250","120,000,000,000" 
Sarah,"3,069","1,180,000,000","384,490","7,200,000,000"
```

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts in your post, try to post samples of input and expected output. These 3 are the most important things which make a post perfect and easy to understand, keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(since OP haven't mentioned samples so couldn't test it).

```
cat script.ksh
read -p "What is your name?: " arg1
if grep -q "$arg1" "names.csv"
then
   printf "%s\n" "We got you!"
else
   printf "%s\n" "Sorry, you are not on the list!"
fi
```

***Problem's fixed in OP's code:***

- Have added `$` to variable `arg1` else it will treat `arg1` as a string while grepping it to `names.csv` file.
- Removed unnecessary `$` in front of `printf`.
- Added `fi` to complete `if` block, please see the manual page for same every `if` should be ended with `fi` to complete its block.

---

---

***EDIT1:***  Tested with own created examples:

Let's say following is our Input_file.

```
cat Input_file
"singh","abc_test","1","2","3"
"abc","singh","1","2","4"
"1","2","3","4","5"
```

script is as follows:

```
cat script.ksh
read -p "What is your name?: " arg1
if grep -q "$arg1" "Input_file"
then
   printf "%s\n" "We got you!"
else
   printf "%s\n" "Sorry, you are not on the list!"
fi
```

Now when I run following code, I get the output.

```
./script.ksh
What is your name?: singh
We got you!
```

---

---

***EDIT2:*** In case you want to match exact string like ***`"singh"`*** in any field of csv then try following.

```
cat script.ksh
read -p "What is your name?: " arg1
if grep -q "\"$arg1\"" "file"
then
   printf "%s\n" "We got you!"
else
   printf "%s\n" "Sorry, you are not on the list!"
fi
```

Testing of above script:

```
./script.ksh
What is your name?: singh1
Sorry, you are not on the list!

./script.ksh
What is your name?: singh
We got you!
```

Comment: @freshmanUCI-, let us delete all comments from here. Please POST these samples as I mentioned before too in your post and let me know then. I am going to delete my comments on here to look it cleaner.

Comment: @freshmanUCI-, are you entering for example `tom` while giving script a variable? and since your Input_file has `Tom` it is failing(May be guessing)?

Comment: What is  cat file.ksh? I am writing on a .s file and the file with the data with a CSV file

Comment: @freshmanUCI-, this is the script where all commands are there(to ask user input etc) and cat means I am printing its contents(displaying) to user on screen. Can you please check my previous comment too once about user entering thing?

Comment: No it is still not working, I have tried it before al well

Comment: @freshmanUCI-, I got it my question is what input are you passing to script  while running it?I showed an example do it like that. 1st- Create a script `file.ksh` for example copy/paste my script's posted one contents there and give `chmod 755 file.ksh` to it then run it by doing `./file.ksh` give enter user when it asks you and then show me here what is not working(basically output of script's run).

Comment: Yes, it is working on that! I have many other lines of code before to implement that if statement, maybe there is a conflic

Comment: It is actually working for the numbers (other columns), I think it is because the names are not within "", thank you so much for help

Comment: To be honest I tried to answer your question here. I am not sure about your complete code, would request you not to change your basic question now. May be you could open a new thread for it with complete requirements mentioned in it. Also give it sometime and when your question you could select one of it as correct answer too, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: If names are not within then may be uppercase or smaller case problem can happen then change `grep` to `grep -i -q`  and let me know then?